# SUMIFS function returning different value than filtering and using SUBTOTAL

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

say I have an Excel table with columns as below.

```
A    B     C 

Date|Name|Amount
```

I want to return the sum of amounts between dates x and y with names {"a","b"}.

I wrote a SUMIFS function

```
=SUMIFS(C:C,B:B,{"a","b"},A:A,">="&DATE(2018,1,1),A:A,"<"&DATE(2018,4,1))
```

Say that function returns 1,500,000

Now if I decide to filter for names "a" and "b", then I filter for the dates I want and use a subtotal function:

```
=SUBTOTAL(109,C:C)
```

it will return a number such as 2,000,000 greater than my SUMIFS function.
Is my mistake in the way im filtering or the SUMIFS function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `=SUMIFS(C:C,B:B,{"a","b"},A:A,">="&DATE(2018,1,1),A:A,"<"&DATE(2018,4,1))`

Is only summing where they are equal to `a` To get it to iterate we need to wrap it in SUM or SUMPRODUCT:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIFS(C:C,B:B,{"a","b"},A:A,">="&DATE(2018,1,1),A:A,"<"&DATE(2018,4,1)))
```

That is the reason for the difference.